# Core Data Child Context

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have 2 questions regarding context creation.

When i access main context via singleton:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
```

Is that the SAME context everytime?

And if i then create a child context like this:

```
let bgContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
```

With Parent as the about main context, is that the SAME child context or is it generating a completely new child context.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, as long as it's a stored property, `appDelegate.managedObjectContext` is the same object every time.

And to your second question, that's a new child context. You can go from [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506792-concurrencytype) to read more from Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> When i access main context via singleton [...] Is that the SAME context everytime?

There's nothing magical or opaque about it. You're getting the managed object context from your app delegate class. Look at your `AppDelegate.swift` and see how it creates that context. This kind of code almost always means that you're getting the same one every time, but it doesn't have to be that way. Go look at your code and see.

> And if i then create a child context like this [...] is that the SAME child context or is it generating a completely new child context.

That line of code initializes a new managed object context. That's what the `NSManagedObjectContext(...)` syntax implies-- creating a new object using a specific initializer method.

Comment: Of course it's not magical. But i ask because i don't understand. I understand i get a context. But want to totally understand when i get the same context and when initialize a new one. So is it because i access the same lazy var via singleton from app delegate i know its the same one?

Comment: If that is how it's declared, and if no other code ever changes the value, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a computed property.

```
appdelegate.managedobjectcontext
```

So somewhere in AppDelegate's implementation, you most likely could find the line:

```
NSManagedObjectContext(...)
```

In this case, AppDelegate is creating it's own managed object context inside its implementation.  `NSManagedObjectContext` is a class and calling `NSManagedObjectContext(...)` instantiates a new object from that class.  So if you called `NSManagedObjectContext(...)` somewhere else, that would be instantiating another object using `NSManagedObjectContext` as it's blueprint.

I hope that makes sense.

Also: [Read under Parent Store for the answer about child contexts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext)